# Difference between HTTP methods

Tags: http

Generally we know the different in get and post method, I want to get clarifications on other methods like head,trace,put,delete, options.

Comment: Did you try googling these terms? I believe there are plenty of resources / tutorials online

Answer (score 0):

GET

The GET method is used to retrieve information from the given server using a given URI. Requests using GET should only retrieve data and should have no other effect on the data.

TRACE

Performs a message loop back test along with the path to the target resource.

HEAD

Same as GET, but it transfers the status line and the header section only.

POST

A POST request is used to send data to the server, for example, customer information, file upload, etc. using HTML forms.

PUT

Replaces all the current representations of the target resource with the uploaded content.

DELETE

Removes all the current representations of the target resource given by URI.

OPTIONS

Describe the communication options for the target resource.

Comment: _"You can get lots of information on Google"_ -- Don't answer off-topic posts, Vote to close instead.  Please read [answer].

Comment: Ok..I am new here..do I delete the answer??The answer is exactly what the user expects